# comparar variable integer desde .get() con integer con tkinter en Python (condición)

Tags: python

quiero saber si el numero devuelto es el mismo que la suma de num1 y num2

```py
num1 = randint(1,10)
num2 = randint(1,10)

res = text.get()
crt = num1 + num2

int(res)
int(crt)

if res == crt:
```

he probado a quitar int(res) e int(crt) pero no sirvió de mucho

Comment: Cual sería el problema?

Comment: `res = int(text.get())` y borra los otros dos `int()` .